Next.js runtime variables with GitHub Actions
App works locally.
I've set up same env variables in my repository and variables which are marked with _PUBLIC_ are visible in app.
But when I try for example to use email logic (which needs NEXT_RESEND_API) server logs that I didn't provide API_KEY, so it doesn't see it.
name: Jest tests
env:
  VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
on: push
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: jest tests
        run: yarn test
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: yarn global add vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=preview --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API: ${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID: ${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID }}
          NEXT_RESEND_API: ${{ vars.NEXT_RESEND_API }}
          NEXT_PRIVATE_PAYPAL_KEY: ${{ vars.NEXT_PRIVATE_PAYPAL_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

How to set up variables which will be used on server side with GitHub Actions correctly? I don't want to add them manually through Vercel interface.
I am using Next.js 14.2.

vercel build doesn't accept any environment variables to set at runtime. Maybe you want to set them with vercel env?

Thank you @jonrsharpe , you are right 
Deploy command has --env options 
run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }} -env NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API=${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPS_API }} --env NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=${{ vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID }}

